# is it acceptable for a muslim to donate to a church for its maintenance and staff?

Tags: islamic-scholar

i recently visited to a church that is also a national heritage. it is in need for renovation and maintenance and i wish to contribute. is it acceptable to contribute to the maintenance of the church/temple of another religion. meaning it would help sustain and grow that other religion. are we allowed to do that or my charity would instead be an act of gunah? please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

No. A church or temple is a place for committing acts of shirk and kufr - such as rituals involving worship of christ or idols. Facilitating sin is not permitted, and is itself a sin.

> #### ولا تعاونوا على الإثم والعدوان
>
> Do not help one another in sin and transgression
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:2](https://quran.com/5/2?translations=203)</sup>

Scholars have noted that it is not permitted to sell or lease land or a building for the purpose of making a church or temple. Similarly Muslims are not permitted to make endowments or bequests for the purpose of their construction or repair or even to donate chairs, lamps or fuel to them, or to donate for the benefit of the staff who work there. Any other donations follow the same principle.

**Ref:**

> [image]
>
> <sup>— [معابد الكفار وأحكامها في بلاد المسلمين](https://ia803001.us.archive.org/27/items/ktp2019-tra15807/ktp2019-tra15807.pdf#page=376)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

The strict application of religious rules, without considering the spirit or intent behind them, can sometimes prevent us from doing what is ethically right in a given situation.

When it comes to the matter of donating to the upkeep of a church or a temple, I believe we should look at your intentions and the broader impact of your actions. If your purpose is to help preserve a piece of national heritage and contribute to society's cultural and historical wealth, then this action could be seen in a positive light. It's not so much about endorsing another religion, but about preserving history, culture, and beauty.

Islam encourages acts of kindness and charity, or sadaqah, to all, regardless of their faith. Your intention to contribute to the maintenance of a historical site could be seen as such an act of kindness.

Let's remember what the Prophet said: "Actions are (judged) by motives (niyyah), so each man will have what he intended..." (Hadith - Bukhari and Muslim)